# Identify subsets of points that have different correlation

Tags: regression, clustering

Apologies for the vague question.

I have a plot similar to the figure below, where I compare the distribution of two variables, i.e. the allele frequency in different datasets.

As you can see most of the data seem to be correlated, and in fact the R2 is close to 1.

However, a small datasets of points seem to have a different correlation - you could fit a line with a different slope, around X=0.12 and also X=0.82.

In this case the extra "diagonals" represent a possible data curation error, and these points should be manually reviewed to make sure the data has been prepared correctly.

Is there an analytical way to determine these type of situations? I need to compare a very large number of datasets, and I cannot check each individual plot, so I was wondering how to implement a check to verify this automatically and flag me the comparisons that I need to verify manually.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Image processing software that can mask regions of both high density (appearing solid black in the image) and low density of data points, leaving these intermediate density regions, could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks much like the concept of **correlation clustering** to me. There are some density-based methods inspired by DBSCAN and OPTICS, that try to be robust to background noise.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! I'll look into correlation clustering.